# How to retrieve value of key from an object inside an array

Tags: arrays, vue.js, javascript-objects

I'm trying to retrieve the merchant name from within the following array:

```
[
  {
    "model": "inventory.merchant",
    "pk": 1, 
    "fields": {
      "merchant_name": "Gadgets R Us",
      "joined": "2020-01-06T07:16:17.365Z"
    }
  },
  {"model": "inventory.merchant", "pk": 2, "fields": {"merchant_name": "H&M", "joined": "2020-01-07T22:21:52Z"}},
  {"model": "inventory.merchant", "pk": 3, "fields": {"merchant_name": "Next", "joined": "2020-01-07T22:22:56Z"}},
  {"model": "inventory.merchant", "pk": 4, "fields": {"merchant_name": "Jill Fashion", "joined": "2020-01-07T22:26:48Z"}}
]
```

I'm using vuejs and have used axios to fetch the above data via an api. I put in an array called `merchants[]`. I'm able to get any item I want from within my html using v-for i.e.

```
<div v-for="merchant in merchants">
  <p>{{ merchant.fields.merchant_name }}</p>
</div>
```

However, in my .js file, doing the following does not work:

```
console.log(this.merchants[0].fields.merchant_name)
```

I get the following error in my console:

```
vue.js:634 [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'fields' of undefined"
```

Please help

Edit:
This is my .js file. I try to log the merchants name in the console from the `merchantName()` computed property:

```
new Vue({
  delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],
  el: "#inventory",

  data: {
    gallery: true,
    inCart: false,
    shipping: false,
    galleryView: "zoom",
    ref: "",
    cart: [],
    isSelected: false,
    selectedClass: "in_cart",
    shippingCost: 2000,
    inventory: [],
    merchants: [],
  },
  methods: {
    zoomGallery(){
      this.galleryView = "zoom"
    },
    back(){
      this.gallery = "thumbnail"
    },
    addToCart(name, merchant, price, qty, image, id){
      var itemClone = {}
      itemClone = {
        "merchant": merchant,
        "name": name,
        "price": price,
        "qty": qty,
        "image": "/media/" + image,
        "id": id,
      }
      this.cart.push(itemClone)
      this.isSelected = true
    },
    removeFromCart(index){
      this.cart.splice(index, 1)
    },
    deleteFromCart(id){
      console.log(id)
      // right now, any caret down button deletes any input
      // I need to use components to prevent that
      if (this.cart.length > 0){
        index = this.cart.findIndex(x => x.id === id)
        this.cart.splice(index, 1)
      }
    },
    viewCart(){
      this.gallery = false
      this.shipping = false
      this.inCart = true
    },
    viewShipping(){
      this.gallery = false
      this.shipping = true
      this.inCart = false
    }
  },
  computed: {
    itemsInCart(){
      return this.cart.length
    },
    subTotal(){
      subTotal = 0
      inCart = this.cart.length
      for (i=0; i<inCart; i++) {
        subTotal += Number(this.cart[i].price)
      }
      return subTotal
    },
    checkoutTotal(){
      return this.subTotal + this.shippingCost
    },
    merchantName(){
      console.log(this.merchants[0])
    },
  },
  beforeMount() {
    axios
      .get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/get_products/").then(response => {
        (this.inventory = response.data)
        return axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/get_merchants/")
      })
      .then(response => {
        (this.merchants = response.data)
      })
  },
});
```

Edit:
Response from console.log(this.merchants) is:

```
[__ob__: Observer]
length: 0
__ob__: Observer
value: Array(0)
length: 0
__ob__: Observer {value: Array(0), dep: Dep, vmCount: 0}
__proto__: Array
dep: Dep
id: 16
subs: Array(0)
length: 0
__proto__: Array(0)
__proto__: Object
vmCount: 0
__proto__:
walk: ƒ walk(obj)
observeArray: ƒ observeArray(items)
constructor: ƒ Observer(value)
__proto__: Object
__proto__: Array
```

Comment: what is the initial value of merchants

Comment: where are you logging ```console.log(this.merchants[0].fields.merchant_name)``` ?

Comment: `<p v-if="merchant">{{ merchant.fields.merchant_name }}</p>`

Comment: Hello @PranavCBalan, there's nothing in merchants. I initialise it as merchants[]

@FatemeFazli I'm just using a component to post it to the console just to see the output i.e. 
`
merchantName(){
      console.log(this.merchant[0].fields.merchant_name)
    }
`

Comment: It seems your data is not ready yet so merchants is empty array: initial value. you should check if data is arrived or not something like: ```if(merchants.length) {console.log(this.merchants[0].fields.merchant_name)}```

Comment: Thanks @PranavCBalan but that is not my problem. What I want to do is retrieve the data in my .js file and use it there.

Comment: Hello @FatemeFazli the data is there. If it wasn't there, `<div v-for="merchant in merchants">` will not work but it is working.  Also, I'm using Vue devtools and it shows the data

Comment: How are you trying to access your data in the js file?

Comment: Can you try console.log(this.merchants) and check if there is any data or not ?

Comment: And I think you should share how and where you console log this.merchants[0].fields.merchant_name

Comment: Hello @NipunJain, I've uploaded my full .js file.

Comment: You guys are right @FatemeFazli, Nipun Jain, it seems the array is empty but why is it that it's not empty for the html i.e. `v-for="merchant in merchants"` works just fine?

Comment: At first it's empty until the data comes from server and when data comes template updates but the console is before data coming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you are trying to console.log `this.merchants` in computed property. Check for computed property of vuejs [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html).

Your data is empty before data from API call even come. So that's why your `this.merchants` is empty.

You can get you `this.merchants` value by using a method and run it after your api call or watching that like this:

```
watch: {
  merchants: function () {
    console.log(this.merchants)
  }
}
```

It will console `this.merchants` array everytime a change happens in it.

Comment: Thanks but this tells me what I'm doing wrong but not the right way to do it. Do you know how I can make it such that the array is not empty.

Comment: Do you want your this.merchants to not empty in computed ? I think you can use `watch` in this case. I am updating my answer to show how.